Скрипт Powershell рассылки разных вложений в Exchange
Cкрипт для рассылки разных вложений.
Надо чтобы отправлял всему списку из email.csv
Сейчас отправляет письмо только последнему в списке
$EmailList = Import-Csv "C:\email.csv"

Сам крипт:
#Папка с файлами
$FileFolder = "C:\Files\"

#Запись лога
$LogFile = "C:\emaillog.txt"

#Файл с почтовыми адресами + имя файла
#Столбец 1 - Email
#Столбец 2 - File
$EmailList = Import-Csv "C:\email.csv"

#Тело письма в XML формате
$Body = Get-Content "C:\email2.html" | out-string

#Почта отправителя + тема письма
$From = "отправитель"
$Subject = "Тут должна быть тема"

# Перебор CSV файла 
ForEach ($Email in $EmailList) {
#Переменные адрес + файл
$To = $Email.Email
$File = $FileFolder+$Email.File
}

     #Отправка письма
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer mail.srv -from $From -to $To -subject $Subject -body $Body -attachment $File -BodyAsHTML -Encoding 'UTF8'
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format u
$LogMessage =  $LogTime+" Emailed "+$Email.Email+" the file "+$File
$LogMessage | Out-File $LogFile -Append



Командлет Send-MailMessage у вас находится за переделами (после) цикла, поэтому отрабатывает только один раз и только с данными для последнего письма

Спасибо! Теперь всё огонь.
